# How can I define such an array?

Tags: java, php, arrays

How can I define such an array?

I need to make an array in JAVA like the one below:

```
Array(
    [0]=> Array(
            [0]=>1
            [1]=>1
            [2]=>1
            )
    [1]=> Array(
            [0]=>4
            [1]=>7
            [2]=>10
            )
     )
```

And how do I read this array using JAVA?

The PHP equivalent of this would be:

```
$a=array( array( 1, 1, 1 ), array( 4, 7, 10 ) );
```

And I can read it like this in PHP:

```
foreach( $a as $v ){
echo $v[0]. " ". $v[1]." ". $v[2]. "\r\n";
}
```

To sum up, I want to define an INT array of size 2, and each element of this array is another array of size 3.
Then I want to read the inside array 3 values during a loop in three different INT variables.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use { } to define arrays

```
int[][] values = {{ 1, 1, 1 }, { 4, 7, 10 }};
```

To print them in a loop like you do

```
for (int[] a : values) 
    System.out.println(a[0] + " " + a[1] + " " + a[2]);
```

I suggest you read up on how arrays work in Java.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare a two-dimensional array. The standard way to do this:

```
int[][] array = new int[][]{
    new int[] {1, 2, 3},
    new int[] {4, 5, 6}
};
```

But you could use more convenient one.

```
int[][] array = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} };
```

To iterate over the array you may use:

```
for(int[] i : array) {
    for(int j : i) System.out.print(i + " ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Thank you both for the answers. This solves my problem :)